# How to mask value of some fields to some specific users in kibana 8.5.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I'm using from Kibana 8.5.3 and I wnat to mask or hide to value of some fields to some specific users.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is called [field level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-level-security.html) in elasticsearch. You can find more information about settings it up in [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-and-document-access-control.html).

Please note that this feature is only available under Platinum or Enterprise license agreements.